# ID space in a SPA

Tags: javascript, dom, data-binding, single-page-application

Looking for an answer from a senior level DOM/JS Architect.

My question is in context of the another [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689046/what-are-the-common-solutions-for-making-clean-id-space-in-a-spa) where it talks about having clean id space in a SPA.

I can not use any data binding frameworks instead it's plain vanilla html due to some constraints, so looking forward to advice from senior architects who knows inner pinnings of data-binding frameworks of how they do it internally.

For example I'm generating some DOM records once http `GET` call returns.

```
Brand.prototype.appendChild = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute("id", "brand_" + data.id);
    li.innerHTML = "<p>" + data.name + "</p>";

    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = "Delete";
    li.appendChild(p);

    p.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
        Brand.prototype.delete.call(self, {id: data.id});
    });

    this.element.appendChild(li);
};

// http delete happens outside via delegate, so it's async
Brand.prototype.delete = function(data) {
    this.delegate.requestConfirm(new model.vo.RequestVO(data, AppConstants.DELETE), "Are you sure you want to delete?");
};

// when http delete request returns, it passes the original data request, I've to find the DOM and delete it
Brand.prototype.removeChild = function(data) {
    var element = document.getElementById("brand_" + data.id);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
};
```

output looks like this.

```
<li id="brand_0">
    <p>Brand Name</p>
    <p>Delete</p>
</li>
```

and if user click on delete, it's an async operation (no promises), and once the delete request returns, I'm looking up the specific id and deleting it.

So the point is I can't have my way without having an ID, I must have an id in the dom for all the records and if I've several sections of a SPA, i'm prefixing id's with a namespace string and of course it can get messy if I've several sections with deep nesting.

Even if I was using some data binding framework, I still have to remove that specific object from the array can call `digest` or whatever to have it deleted.

**So the question becomes, is there way to have CRUD work without declaring ids in plain vanilla JS?**

**Edit** after guest271314's suggestion.

```
Brand.prototype.appendChild = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = "<p>" + data.name + "</p>";

    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = "Delete";
    li.appendChild(p);

    p.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        Brand.prototype.delete.call(self, {id: data.id, event: event});
    });

    this.element.appendChild(li);
};

Brand.prototype.removeChild = function(data) {
    var element = data.event.target;
    var grandparent = element.parentNode.parentNode;
    grandparent.removeChild(element.parentNode);
};
```

Comment: What is purpose of `return function(){}` within event handler, and `(data.id)` following event handler?

Comment: Still not sure what issue is?

Comment: there's no issue, just looking for a better way and technique so I don't have to rely too much on dom id's especially for delete, is there a way to have CRUD work without depending on an ID, I'm wondering if data-binding frameworks figured out a way without using ID's.

Comment: Basically the linked question kinda gave off an idea as if ID's are evil

Comment: You can use `event.target` or `event.currentTarget` within event handler to get the element where event occurred.

Comment: wow, yes I could pass along the event besides the id, light bulb :)

Comment: I've edited based on your suggestion, it worked now I'm no longer dependent on defining Id's generated content in DOM, please review my edits, post your answer with any other suggestions. Great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the target of an event within an event handler using `event.target` or `event.currentTarget`, instead of relying on the `id` of an element.